# Is it possible to run JavaScript in Textmate?

Tags: macos, javascript, textmate

If I try to run it now I get a XCode error. Do I need to install a JavaScript interpreter on my computer?

Comment: How do you want to "run" JavaScript independently of any browser?

Comment: Very good point, of course it is kind of pointless, but wouldn't it be possible to run very basic programs without the browser stuff with an interpreter? JavaScript is used for server stuff lately right?, so I guess there must be some kind of browser independent interpreter, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### `javascript-tools`

First of all, there's the [`javascript-tools` Bundle](https://github.com/johnmuhl/javascript-tools-tmbundle), which offers some productivity tools such as Lint syntax checking, YUI compression, bookmarklet creation, and more.

---

### Creating your own bundle

OS X comes with a JS interpreter found under `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc`. You can symlink it to your PATH to have it available everywhere.

For example:

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc /usr/local/bin
```

Check if it works by just typing:

```
jsc
```

You should land in a console.

[image]

Now, enter TextMate and open the bundle editor by going to *Bundles » Bundle Editor » Show Bundle Editor*. In the JavaScript bundle, create a new command by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button below.

Set the *Input* to *Entire Document*, and the *Output* to *Discard*. Set the keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. Now, paste the [following script](http://metaskills.net/2010/07/09/interactive-javascript-console-with-textmate/) into the command area itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/escape.rb'

def terminal_script_filepath
  %|tell application "Terminal"
      activate
      do script "jsc -i #{e_as(e_sh(ENV['TM_FILEPATH']))}"
    end tell|
end

open("|osascript", "w") { |io| io << terminal_script_filepath }
```

This should look like the following:

[image]

And you're done. Try it by saving a JS file and pressing the keyboard shortcut.

[image]

---

### Using Google's V8 instead

You can install [Google's V8 Javascript engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), it's free and open source, and comes for every major OS.

Now, to install it, you either need to [build it yourself](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html), or use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation).

Install Homebrew first:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Then install the V8 engine:

```
brew install v8
```

This takes a while to compile. Now, when you're done, you can adapt the script above to use V8 instead. Just change the line with `do script` to:

```
do script "v8 #{e_as(e_sh(ENV['TM_FILEPATH']))}"
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you think this will allow me to run JavaScript scripts in textmate too? (I cant try it right now, I am at work)

Comment: This *does* run JavaScript from TextMate, see my line about the TextMate bundle editor :) (It just opens a console for doing it … might be possible to run it in a TextMate window, but I'll have to see about that)

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I didnt read this very carefully yet