# How to get a simple Javascript console and output

Tags: macos, software-rec, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run JavaScript in Textmate?](https://superuser.com/questions/352976/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-in-textmate)

I'm learning javascript at [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com)

They have a website with a js console and an editor.

But I can't find anything that resembles it to run localy on my Mac.

I just want an editor and a way to run the .js which will prompt, alert, show output and console.log

I have textmate but none of the pages I have found on using e.g. node.js to run the code gives me any good output.

Any suggestion is good right now....

Comment: WHy don't you run the js commands in Safari?

Comment: As you can see, TextMate does that, but you don't have a real console to work with, so I'd stick to the browser.

Comment: My files won't run. Should a file start with something to let Safari know it's a js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use your browser's developer tool's console? All modern browsers have it.

In Chrome and Safari, press <kbd>Cmd - Option - I</kbd> and select the console tab. It may not be able to load .js files directly, but you can copy and paste.

Comment: That's pretty sweet, I didn't know about that

Comment: Changed the commands to the OS X ones, the OP is using a Mac.

Comment: My files won't run. Should a file start with something to let Safari know it's a js?

Comment: Typically a browser will not run a .js file unless it is call by &lt;script> tag. What I have been trying to suggest is you copy the contents of the .js file and paste them into the developer tool's console. Alternatively, you could just write a dummy html file that contains just a &lt;script> tag. To display the result, use either document.write() or console.log().

Comment: I wrote a dummy file as you said. The missing pice was '<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>'

Answer (score -1):

You can use Firebug. This is a browser extension, with a javascript command line: http://getfirebug.com/commandline.

Adobe Acrobat has an Acrobat Javascript Console: http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console.

BTW, why do you need this? You start using a javascript **editor** on section 5 of Getting Started with Programming.

Comment: I need it because I try to do a few assignments on my own. And there is no simple way for saving and making your own projects.